# How does one display thumbnail images for TGA files with OpenFileDialog?

Tags: winforms, windows-7, thumbnails, preview, openfiledialog

Is it possible to show TGA thumbnails in OpenFileDialog? When using the System.Windows.Controls.OpenFileDialog control to browse image folders Windows 7, it will show preview thumbnails icons for JPG, PNG, or BMP image files. Unfortunately, Windows does *not* show previews for TGA files. However, Windows *does* show TGA preview thumbnails in Windows *Explorer*. Is there an extension or setting that will show TGA thumbnails in OpenFileDialog?

OpenFileDialog shows thumbnails for JPG files:
[image: OpenFileDialog with JPGs]

OpenFileDialog does NOT show TGA thumbnails:
[image: OpenFileDialog with JPGs]

However, Explorer DOES show TGA thumbnails:
[image: OpenFileDialog with JPGs]

Comment: Yes, I'm on x64 running a x86 application. I had to install the 32-bit version of a TGA thumbnail app to get thumbs in my 32-bit app. (See my own answer below.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An artist at my company provided a solution. Windows 7 has no built-in support for TGA thumbnails, but there are 3rd party applications such as [MysticThumbs](http://mysticcoder.net/mysticthumbs.html) that add support for TGA files. In fact, the only reason Windows Explorer showed TGA thumbs in my example was because I had MysticThumbs installed. However, the application's OpenFileDialog did not show thumbnails because it was a 32-bit application and I had installed the 64-bit version of MysticThumbs. I installed the 32-bit version of MysticThumbs in addition to the 64-bit version, and now I see TGA thumbnails in both Windows Explorer and my 32-bit application.

Comment: Well, glad I guessed that one correctly.  Close your thread please.

Answer (score -1):

[FreeImage.NET](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) can also open TGA images.